# Dynamic Pivot with varying columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, dynamicquery, dynamic-pivot

I have a POA Code dynamic pivot that pulls data from a DX temp table and inserts the data into a temp POA table.
The issue I'm having is that there is a possibility of up to 35 different columns that can be returned.  Depending on the month there could be 15 columns (`POA1...POA15`) or there could be all 35 columns (`POA1...POA35`).  I join this dynamic pivot temp table on another patient table.  My problem is, I need to show all 35 columns even if some of the columns do not exist in the temp POA table.

```
--Pivot DX POA Codes
DECLARE @POANAME VARCHAR(40)
SELECT @POAName = '##tmpPOA'

DECLARE @colsPOA NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @colsPOA = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    '],[' + 'POA' + CAST(Dx.RowNum AS NVARCHAR)
    FROM #tmpDX DX
    ORDER BY '],[' + 'POA' + CAST(Dx.RowNum AS NVARCHAR)
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),1,2,'') + ']'

DECLARE @queryPOA NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @queryPOA = 'N
    SELECT
       EncObjID,
       '+ 
       @colsPOA
       +' INTO ' + POAName + '
       FROM 
       (SELECT
            Dx.EncObjID
            ,''POA'' + Dx.RowNum AS RowNum
            ,Dx.POAMne
        FROM #tmpDx Dx
       ) p
       PIVOT
           (
            MIN([POAMne])
            FOR RowNum IN
            ( ' + @colsPOA + ' )
           ) AS pvt'
EXECUTE(@queryPOA)
```

I'm receiving an Invalid Column Name in my patient query because some of the columns don't exist in `##tmpPOA`. I thought about creating a temp table called `#tmpDxPOA` and doing an insert (`Insert Into #tmpDxPOA select * from ##tmpPOA`), but that doesn't work (I receive a Column Name or number of supplied values does not match error).

Any thoughts on how to create all 35 columns even if there isn't any data?  I don't care if they're null, I just need to have those place holders in the main patient query and it doesn't help that the number of columns returned varies every month.

Comment: following your logic with another table with all the columns you need, the 35 POA, the insert also needs to be dynamic and only insert the columns that you did the pivot on.. something like "insert into #othertable ("+colsPOA+")select "+colsPOA+" from POAName  select * from #othertable"

Comment: can you handle it in the presentation layer?

Comment: @Beth - No, I have this data and the patient data going into another temp table that feeds many unioned queries.  I guess I could hard code the column names in the query that creates the dynamic columns.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing, can you provide the schema for #tmpDX?

Comment: It looks like you don't really need dynamic SQL here.  You could just write a query with 35 subqueries in the SELECT to get the data for the columns.  Then you could have columns with no data to be null or you could control the output as desired.

Comment: @mxix I just tried your suggestion with a couple of modifications and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!  Here's what I ended up with:
    DECLARE POASQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET POASQL = N'INSERT INTO #tmpPOAFinal (EncObjID,'+colsPOA+') SELECT * FROM ##tmpPOA'
    EXECUTE(POASQL)  
I put this after my EXECUTE(@queryPOA) statement.

Comment: Glad you got it running, it was your idea anyway ,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @mxix I was able to come up with the following:

```
DECLARE @POASQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @POASQL = N'INSERT INTO #tmpPOAFinal (EncObjID,'+@colsPOA+') SELECT * FROM ##tmpPOA' 
EXECUTE(@POASQL)
```

I put this after the `EXECUTE(@queryPOA)` in my main query.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work with Dynamic SQL the rows/colums need to exists more than zero times.  Whether it be for one or more patient.  I would try to fan out the number of POA possibilities right off the bat and then left outer join to get the actual values back.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpPOA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpPOA
CREATE TABLE #tmpPOA (POA varchar(10)) 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpPatient') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpPatient
CREATE TABLE #tmpPatient (Patient varchar(15))
INSERT INTO #tmpPatient VALUES ('ABC123'),('ABC456'),('ABC789')


DECLARE @POAFlag as INT = 0

WHILE @POAFlag <36
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #tmpPOA
VALUES('POA' +CONVERT(varchar,@POAFlag))
SET @POAFlag = @POAFlag + 1

END
SELECT * FROM #tmpPOA
CROSS JOIN #tmpPatient
```

This should fan out all of the possibilities of the 35DXCodes for you to get their POA flag.